# ¿Como leer datos de una tabla de un archivo excel en c#?

Tags: c#, excel

Veran quiero hacer una aplicacion donde yo valide la existencia de un dato en una columna de excel, es decir en un textbox poner el dato que quiero buscar, si existe mandarme un message box solo para validar y en caso de que no exista, me tire un mensaje diciendo que no existe el dato, hasta el momento solo encontre esta informacion pero no me resulta clara del todo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El codigo debe ir como texto

Comment: Cómo, exactamente, esperas que te ayudemos? Qué necesitas de nosotros, específicamente?

Comment: Bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) gracias por ayudar a esta comunidad. pero debes ser mas especifico, muéstranos que has intentado, dale un vistazo al siguiente contenido [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

puedes buscar el valor en resultDataSet, no tengo fresco como hacerlo pero me imagino que iteras primero sobre los 'rows' y en cada row sobre 'columns' para buscar el texto en especifico.